# getting the value of the single field output using the codeigniter active record

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

the following function is supposed to read the name of the given asset code from the database. but it triggers the error: "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
function sban_name($asset){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('asset_types');
    $this->db->where('code',$asset);
    return $this->db->get()->result()->row('name');
}
```

All I want is to have the name of the asset returned back to the controller! Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `row()` like,

```
return $this->db->get()->row()->name;
```

Comment: I need this data in model here this is my query

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail = '$email' AND usertype = 1 AND usertype = 2")->row()->useremail;

Answer (score 11):

Use `row()` for a single row, and `result()` for multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

do like this, asset_types is your table name

```
function sban_name($asset){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('asset_types');
    $this->db->where('code',$asset);
    return $this->db->get('asset_types');
}
```

And in your controller acess it like

```
$result=$this->modelname->sban_name('$asset')->row();
$name=$result->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to check if the record that satisfies the conditions even exists in the database. Code for the model:

```
function sban_name($asset){
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('asset_types');
    $this->db->where('code',$asset);
    $row = $this->db->get()->row();
    if (isset($row)) {
        return $row->name;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Simply call the function from the controller like so:

```
 $response = $this->model_name->sban_name($asset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code of block , I already checked and works fine:

```
function sban_name($asset)
{
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('asset_types');
    $this->db->where('code', $asset);
    return $this->db->get()->row()->name;
}
```