# Database type int use value for calculation with

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am working (learning) on the CodeIgniter platform. The code is not much different from plain PHP except for the mysql syntax

**Problem**

A user has a balance of $100. He then signs up for a tournament. The entry fee from the tournament is $50. Thus:

1. Get Balance From DB
2. Subtract 5$0 from value retrieved from DB
3. Update database with new value.

The above should be fairly simple but I am getting strange results.

### Games_model

```
public function get_balance($userID)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT balance FROM users WHERE userID = '$userID'";
        $stmnt = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($stmnt->num_rows() > 0){
           $balance =  $stmnt->result();
           return $balance;
    }
return false;
    }

    public function update_balance($userID){
        //get balance
        $balance = $this->get_balance($userID);
        //charge for pool entry
        $newBalance = (int)$balance - (int)50;
        var_dump($newBalance);
        echo '<h1>'.$newBalance.'</h1>';
        $this->db->set('balance', (int)$newBalance);
        $this->db->where("userID", $userID); //table column field, second argument
        $this->db->update('users');

    }
```

### Games Controller

```
//Charge for picks #TODO add a check if user has enough funds to enter!!!!!
            echo $this->games_model->update_balance($this->session->userID);
            //Transferring data to Model uploaded
           echo $this->games_model->record_picks($data['picks']);

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('games/record_picks', $data);
            //$this->load->view('templates/upcoming_fixtures_tbl', $data['games']);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        }
```

**What I did**

The type of `balance` in the db was of type `int()` however getting that value and subtracting 50 gave wrong results. I then changed `balance` field to type `varchar()` and tried to subtract 50. Still wrong result.

Finally I attempted type casting, as you can see in code above, however it still produces wrong result.

**Result I am getting**

In this example I get the user's `balance` which is 150. I then attempt to minus 50 from it. And the result I get back is....`-49` which is real strange.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I have debugged the method `get_balance()` and *can confirm the correct balance is retrieved.* The problem happens in the `update_balance()` method.

**Update 2:**

When I try to `echo` $balance = $this->get_balance($userID); inside the `update_balance()` method, I get an array to string conversion. So I suspect that is where the problem is.

> Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion  Filename:
>   models/Games_model.php Line Number: 130

**Update 3**

`var_dump()` of method `get_balance()`

> array (size=1)   0 => 
>       object(stdClass)[41]
>         public 'balance' => string '-49' (length=3)

Comment: When you echo the variables in `update_balance()` do you get the expected result? Or is it the update query that is not working as intended?

Comment: I can confirm the update query is working since it updates `balance` with `49`. Let me `echo` some vars inside `update_balance` and report back

Comment: @Mike please see update 2

Comment: You should be using either an integer type (smallint, int, bigint) or a float.  You should not be using varchar to store numbers!

Comment: I know I simply tried it as a debug

Comment: `$balance =  $stmnt->result();` <-- I don't know CodeIgniter, but I'm pretty sure that returns the entire result set, not the single column of the first row.

Comment: @Mike a `var_dump()` on `$balance = $stmnt->result()` displays the `balance` correctly.

Comment: @Mike yes exactly the issue

Comment: @gview please see above comment. Thank you

Comment: The issue is that it's a result, which is an array.  Even though your result only has one column, it's still an array.  var_dump() it and see.

Comment: @gview yes, you are correct. However when I try to call it and loop over it as an array I still get the same incorrect result. Example I tried this inside `update_balance()`  `//call get_balance as an array -- $balances[] = $this->get_balance($userID);
         foreach ($balances as $balance){
             $newBalance = (int)$balance - (int)50;
         }`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee `var_dump` doesn't *just* output the value of a variable, it also outputs the type and iterates through arrays/objects recursively as well. It is important when debugging that you make sure the variable type is what you would expect as well.

Comment: Update your question with the var_dump output and I'll tell you what you need to fix it.  Also, can there be more than one balance row per user?  Seems like you wouldn't want that, but it might be possible.

Comment: What if you do `return  $stmnt->row()->balance;` in your `get_balance` method?

Comment: @gview Not likely a users table would contain multiple rows with the same user id.

Comment: @gview & Mike thank you for your ongoing help. Gimmie 1-min to do requested instructions

Comment: @Mike, good point, I glossed over that it was querying the user table.

Comment: @gview please see `var_dump()` result on update question under Update 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the value of the single field output using the codeigniter active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954107/getting-the-value-of-the-single-field-output-using-the-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: Well, as you can see it's an array of objects.  The provided answer is the right way to handle it.  Also, the balance value is -49, so any addition you do will reflect that until you fix it.

Comment: @gview Yip figured it out , and lesson learned. All part of the learning process. Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Note** : set your field type `int` instead of typecasting the `balance` column in table

*return single row instead. your `get_balance` should be like this :*

```
public function get_balance($userID)
{
  $this->db->select('balance');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where('userID',$userID);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
     return $query->row()->balance;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Your `update_balance` method should be like this :

```
public function update_balance($userID)
{
    $balance = $this->get_balance($userID);

    $newBalance = ! empty($balance) ? ($balance - 50) : NULL;
    var_dump($newBalance);
    echo '<h1>'.$newBalance.'</h1>';

    $this->db->where("userID", $userID); 
    $this->db->update('users',['balance' => $newBalance]);
}
```

Comment: By using this approach (two trips to the db), there is a greater risk of encountering a problem due to a race condition. Codeigniter is capable of updating one column using another column or value.