# No MySQL Table ID is passing correctly

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have some MySQL Tables and want to get the exact ID of a table named as tbl_voucher in my Codigniter project. Used the following model to do that.

## UI Edit

```
public function getPendingStationaryVoucher()
{    
     $approve_link = anchor('item/recommendVoucher/$1', '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> ' . 'Recommend Voucher', 'class="s_edit"');
        $action = '<div class="text-center"><div class="btn-group text-left">'
            . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Actions<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
           
            <li>' . $approve_link . '</li>';
    

    $this->load->library('datatables');
    $this->datatables
    ->select("voucher_id, created_date, created_by,  file_no, description, 
    amount AS amount, tbv.payment_status AS cs")
    ->from('tbl_voucher tbv')
   
    ->where('tbv.voucher_type= "Stationary" ')
    ->where('tbv.payment_status= "Created" ');
   
    $this->datatables->add_column("Actions", $action, "tbv.voucher_id");       
    $this->db->order_by('tbv.voucher_id', 'DESC');
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
    public function getVoucherDataById($id) {

    $this->db->select('tbv.voucher_id, tbv.update_stock_id, tbv.created_date, tbv.created_by,
         tbv.description,  tbv.file_no, tbv.amount, tbv.payment_status');
    $this->db->from('tbl_voucher tbv');
    $this->db->join('store_update_stock sus','sus.update_stock_id=tbv.update_stock_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tbl_supplier sup','sup.supplier_id=sus.supplier', 'left');
    $this->db->where('tbv.voucher_type="Stationary"');  
    $this->db->where('tbv.voucher_id',$id);
    $this->db->order_by('tbv.voucher_id');
    $q = $this->db->get();        

    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code is working properly.

Desired Output :-
I want to get tbv.voucher_id as 1 or 2 or 3 ....etc (Exact Number).

Output :-
But the code returns the tbv.voucher_id as "tbv.voucher_id". If the following line commented, array values are outs correctly as follows :

```
$this->db->where('tbv.voucher_id',$id);

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [voucher_id] => 1
            [update_stock_id] => 2
            [created_date] => 2023-08-07 20:51:34
            [created_by] => cssso1
            [description] => Stationary Payments - Jul 2023
            [file_no] => css/02/02/76
            [amount] => 15300.00
            [payment_status] => Created
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [voucher_id] => 3
            [update_stock_id] => 4
            [created_date] => 2023-08-07 22:23:12
            [created_by] => cssso1
            [description] => Stationary Payments - Aug 2023
            [file_no] => css/02/02/76
            [amount] => 2000.00
            [payment_status] => Created
        )

)
```

But I want to get only one values of array at a time that's relevant to the voucher_id like 1 or 3.

What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: "Code is working properly." Are you sure? "return $q->result();" [Are you sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16954107)

Comment: @ 
Solarflare
 . Yes. Code has not erros. But didn't return desired ID. That was the problem

Comment: do you mean you are getting different voucher_ids even on querying for specific voucher_id ..?

Comment: @ 
Sudhir Bastakoti. Yes. Correct. That result is getting after commented the line, $this->db->where('tbv.voucher_id',$id);, Otherwise, do not outs anything.

Comment: first check voucher type.  then try to change `$this->db->where('tbv.voucher_type="Stationary"');` to `$this->db->where('tbv.voucher_type',"Stationary");`

Comment: @ 
Salz
 . No. thats not the issue. Even totally removed this line, there outs the same.

Comment: Comment out the `select` line, so that the result will include all columns. This will help you to see the result of the the joins and wheres, which will help you locate the problem.

Comment: hmm I'm still confused lmao. please explain the expected output as well. if you want only one record maybe you should add **$this->db->group_by("tbv.voucher_id");** too

Comment: @Salz
 . I want to get a specific record from a record set at a time when selecting that specific record ID in the UI. Pls. refer to the edit